# Folder structure for rabbitmq xml configured application project

Tags: xml, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to run few rabbitmq xml configured application codes. I came across an example - https://pamlesleylu.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/hello-world-for-spring-amqp-and-rabbitmq/ . Can anyone tell me what would be the correct folder structure for this example?

Comment: you can take a look for full examples here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples

Comment: The link contains projects that make use of spring boot auto configuration. I am looking for projects that have queues, exchanges and bindings configured in xml file

Comment: xml to configuration and vise-versa is somewhat straight forward... at least you can see best practices for project's structures you asked about

Answer (score 0):

See the [amqp Spring Integration Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/amqp).

It's a Spring Integration app, but its configuration includes some basic [Spring AMQP infrastructure](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/amqp/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/integration/spring-integration-context.xml#L45).

```
<!-- Infrastructure -->

<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" host="localhost" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="si.test.queue" />

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="si.test.exchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="si.test.queue" key="si.test.binding" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>
```